# Selenium selected option in dropdown not displayed correctly

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following issue with Selenium Webdriver. There are two dropdown menus on a page i am testing "brand" and "items". The options of "items" depend on which brand you choose. I am trying to iterate through all possible choices and print brand-item pairs. I use two possible ways to pick an option from each dropdown menu
Using Select():

```
def retryingSelectOption(name,n):
    result=False
    attempts=0
    while attempts<5:
        try:
            element=Select(driver.find_element_by_name(name))
            element.select_by_index(n)
            print element.all_selected_options[0].text
            result=True
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
        attempts+=1
    return result
```

And using .click():

```
def retryingClickOption(name,n):
    result=False
    attempts=0
    while attempts<5:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_name(name).find_elements_by_tag_name("option")[n].click()
            result=True
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
        attempts+=1
    return result
```

My problem is that at ,what seem to me as random moments (sometimes it works sometimes it does not), even though the above functions return True and printing out the selected option shows me the correct answer, the browser still displays the previous option. So basically Selenium tells me i have picked the right option but the browser displays the previous one.No idea what is wrong.
After checking it a bit more it seems that if i manually click somewhere in the browser the option actually refreshes to the correct value. It seems like the browser hangs.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a silly question but if either method is giving you the correct output, does it really matter if your browser is showing the wrong selection? For most automated testing like this, you won't likely be watching the browser, you'll start your suite and go off and do something else and check the results when its finished.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your comment. the issue is the following. my code deals with timing issues (i.e time taken to reload the page) and StaleElementReferenceExceptions by waiting for some other element to become stale and then find it again when it is fresh. If the browser doesn't load the correct option then that element will never become stale (because the page will not refresh with the new data) and so my code gets stuck.

Comment: Is this reproducible in other browsers?